# Resolving of lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

this is from an examination paper online, but it has no worked solutions. I have trouble understanding why and how the answer is 32 from this code, like how is the priority of resolving brackets like. I personally resolved the following print expression to foo(bar)(8) before getting stuck, as foo should take the first parameter to be a value preferably and 2nd parameter from the lambda to be a function, this case, bar and 8 are at different places.

```
    def bar(x):
        return lambda y: x(x(y))

    def foo(y):
        return lambda x: x(y)

    print((foo(bar)(bar)(lambda x:x*2)(2)))
```

I would appreciate a detailed answers or any sites where I can build my foundation on resolving lambdas like this. Learning this on my own and I dont really have a good understanding on this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This feels more like a lambda calculus exercise than a Python one. It's a matter of expanding all the definitions, simplifying the given expression.

```
foo(bar)(bar)(lambda x:x*2)(2)
# expanding foo(bar)
(lambda x: x(bar))(bar)(lambda x:x*2)(2)
# beta reduction
bar(bar)(lambda x:x*2)(2)
# expanding bar(bar)
(lambda y: bar(bar(y)))(lambda x:x*2)(2)
# beta reduction
bar(bar(lambda x:x*2))(2)
# expanding bar(lambda ...)
bar(lambda y: (lambda x:x*2)((lambda x:x*2)(y)))(2)
# let's call g = lambda y: (lambda x:x*2)((lambda x:x*2)(y))
bar(g)(2)
# expanding bar(g)
(lambda y: g(g(y))(2)
# beta reduction
g(g(2))
# expanding innermost g
g((lambda y: (lambda x:x*2)((lambda x:x*2)(y)))(2))
# beta reduction
g((lambda x:x*2)((lambda x:x*2)(2)))
# beta reduction
g((lambda x:x*2)(2*2))
# arithmetic
g((lambda x:x*2)(4))
# beta reduction
g(4*2)
# arithmetic
g(8)
# expanding g
...
```

I think you now get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed rigourous math. I see the key skills here are tracking the brackets for the lambda function and the bracket immediately beside it. Gotta work on my speed.

I have a similar problem for compose. Cant seem to figure it out with the current eg u gave me.

       

It says <code>thrice(f)(n)</code> returns same result as <code>f(f(f(n)))</code>. Do u mind simplifying the body of lambda code in thrice to prove to me that this is true?

Comment: sry formatting errors happening, tried to edit in the previous comment but apparently I edited too many times and failed.
 
       
        `def compose(f,g):
            return lambda x: f(g(x))`

        `def thrice(f):
            return compose(compose(f,f),f)`

prove that `thrice(f)(n)` returns same result as `f(f(f(n)))`

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth You need to expand the definitions, something like `thrice(f)(n) = c(c(f,f),f)(n) = c(f,f)(f(n)) = f(f(f(n)))`, with a few more lambdas in the middle, if one wants all the basic steps.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, I got it  :) What other kind of math concepts do I need for Computer Science? Besides this example of lambda calculus.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth It really depends on how much computer science one wants to study. I'd say that virtually any major field of math (including the most abstract ones) found some important application in computer science. Try browsing both cs.SE and cstheory.SE and you'll find plenty of references. The good news is that you don't need to know all of that math in advance; as long as you're able to pick it up as needed you'll be fine.